# Partition of connected space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am looking for some examples of partitioning of a connected topological space $X$ by pairwise disjoint closed connected subspaces. Off course this partition would consist of infinitely many such connected closed sets otherwise the space $X$  would not be connected.

Also, I know that we can take singleton sets, but I am looking for subspaces which are not totally disconnected.

Thank you.

Comment: Let $V$ be any connected topological vector space. Let $W$ be a closed connected subspace of $V$. Then the cosets of $W$ give such a partition. The canonical example is partitioning $\mathbb{R}^n$ into planes of some dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane ($\Bbb R^2$, standard topology) is a disjoint union of circles around the origin (one for each radius, including $0$, so $\{0\}$ as well). All of the circles are connected, and the plane is too. Parallel lines will work too.

By Sierpinski's theorem, we cannot have a countable partition of closed sets for a compact and connected Hausdorff $X$ (a continuum).

Comment: I don't understand why circles would be disjoint though. Wouldn't boundary of two consecutive circle common ?

Comment: @LordKK they’re circles with the same origin of different radii. Sure they are disjoint. Note: a circle is not a disk, but one-dimensional at most.

Comment: Ahh.. thanks. Got it.